# mysql search a column containing an array

Tags: php, mysql

As I search for results I find a lot of answers were the mysql contains the needle and PHP provides the haystack... any array.

I need it the other way around. My table has a column called `supervisor_ids` containing an array such as this...

`a:2:{i:0;i:9999;i:1;i:1;}`

In my PHP code I have a value saved in a variable... `$supervisor`

How do I search the 'supervisor_ids' column for $supervisor?

I would assume something like...

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $supervisor IN 'supervisor_ids'` but that doesn't work

## UPDATE

I just found out that if the table column contains an list like `9999,1,5,678` as opposed to an array... `a:2:{i:0;i:9999;i:1;i:1;}`

this would work...

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET($supervisor,supervisor_ids)`

What is the equivalent to search it when it is an array?

Comment: You can try `"SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'supervisor_ids' LIKE '%" . $supervisor . "%' "`. The `LIKE` operator will search for a pattern and the `%` acts as a wildcard matching 0 or more characters. The `REGEXP` operator could also work

Comment: is this is a regular thing, you need to normalise the data, storing data this way leads to all sorts of difficulties https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with something like this:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE supervisor_ids LIKE "%i:$supervisor;%";`

if the value of `$supervisor` in PHP is 9, the actual query will be:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE supervisor_ids LIKE "%i:9;%";`

and will match all serialized arrays that are like this:

a:...:{...;i:9;...;}

Assuming supervisor_ids column contains only PHP serialized arrays, this should work fine.

Comment: "i" is static string, from serialized array, assuming $supervisor are all integers, your arrays will always have "i" before the actual id value as a hint that the value describes an integer.

Comment: If `$supervisor` is `9`, your code will also match `94` or `967` or ...

Comment: That's good but your UPDATE code is incorrect, as it is a string value you need to use `FIND_IN_SET` as OP did in the edit to the question.